# react-native-track-player Android Remote Control Options

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, notifications, react-native-track-player

When a react-native application using `react-native-track-player` runs on Android, the notification center *(Notification Center and Control Center in Xiaomi devices on MIUI 12)* becomes laggy. It appears to me that the player tries to open something in the notification center but fails and retries over and over.
I checked my app info in the setting and I saw the following:

[image]

I believe there's a problem in managing the remote control options in Android. I have no idea what is happening on the project's Android side since I'm a react-native developer but it seems that it's trying to send the meta info and control options of the music as a notification, which causes serious performance issues.

I faced this issue while testing on various android devices:

- Xiaomi a2 lite running Android 10
- Xiaomi Redmi note8 Pro running Android 10
- Samsung A31 running Android 10

This is how I have initialized my player:

```js
function NewPlayer() {
 const events = [
   Event.PlaybackTrackChanged,
   Event.PlaybackQueueEnded,
   Event.PlaybackError,
   Event.RemotePause,
   Event.RemoteNext,
   Event.RemotePrevious,
   Event.RemotePlay,
   Event.RemotePause,
   Event.RemoteStop,
   Event.RemoteSeek,
   Event.RemoteDuck,
 ];
 useTrackPlayerEvents(events, event => {
   switch (event.type) {
     case Event.RemoteDuck:
       pauseSong();
       break;
     case Event.PlaybackError:
       console.warn(
         'An error occured while playing the current track.',
         event,
       );
       break;
     case Event.RemoteNext:
       playNextSong();
       break;
     case Event.RemotePrevious:
       playPrevSong();
       break;
     case Event.RemotePlay:
       playSong();
       break;
     case Event.RemotePause:
       pauseSong();
       break;
     case Event.RemoteStop:
       pauseSong();
       break;
     case Event.RemoteSeek:
       TrackPlayer.seekTo(event.position);
       break;
     default:
   }
 });

 useEffect(() => {
   // Initialize
   TrackPlayer.setupPlayer({
     iosCategory: IOSCategory.Playback,
     // iosCategoryOptions:
     iosCategoryMode: IOSCategoryMode.Default,
   });
   TrackPlayer.updateOptions({
     stopWithApp: true,
     capabilities: [
       Capability.Play,
       Capability.Pause,
       Capability.SkipToNext,
       Capability.SkipToPrevious,
       Capability.Stop,
       Capability.SeekTo,
     ],
     compactCapabilities: [Capability.Play, Capability.Pause],
   });
 }, []);
 return null;
}
```

I'm using `react-navigation` v5 and my player is instantiated in the root of the project:

```xml
<Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate persistor={persistor}>
        <SafeAreaProvider>
          <StatusBar barStyle="light-content" />
          <RootStack authContext={authContext} />
          <NewPlayer />
        </SafeAreaProvider>
      </PersistGate>
</Provider>
```

**Hint**: *I have also reported [this issue](https://github.com/react-native-kit/react-native-track-player/issues/1036) on the GitHub:*

***How can I solve this issue?***